# SQL query for retrieving non-negative integer data

Tags: sql

I need a query which will retrieve non-negative Integer values only from a given table

Lets say I have a table `A` and the query `select* from A` will retrieve all contents from it. Now I want to write a query which will give me only non-negative values.

Assumption: All columns of the table contain negative/positive/zero Integer values as well as characters.

Comment: In where clause i wrote <column name> > 0 | <column name> = 0 it gives me results ...but for 50 columns this query will be too long

Comment: @user1466466 why query length is such a big issue?

Comment: @Iaroslav Kovtunenko:its a big issue because it will increase my java code lines in which i intend to embed this query. So it would be wise to optimize my query if possible

Comment: @user1466466 you could also store the query somewhere else, so it wouldn't mess up your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from A where col1 >=0 and col2 >=0 and .... and colN>=0
```

Just replace col1...colN with your column names.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT FIELD1  
FROM TABLE
WHERE FIELD1 >= 0

UNION ALL

SELECT FIELD2  
FROM TABLE
WHERE FIELD2 >= 0
```

Comment: Non-negative values are required, so replace "> 0" with ">= 0". UNION ALL includes duplicates in the resultset. Use UNION instead. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms180026.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the only way:

```
select * from A
where col1 > 0 and col2 > 0 and col3 > 0 and col4 > 0 ... and coln > 0
```

Comment: but it will be too long right ?? if possible i need an optimised one

Comment: how many columns do you have? Even if they are too many you normally wouldn't add new columns to the table so you just write your query once. Alternatively you can make a view (using the same query of course) so you just use the view in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Simply?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE FIELD > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tablea where COLUMN > 0;`

Comment: i intend to embed this query in my Java code. So if possible i need a short query which would fulfill my requirements

Comment: @user1466466 , this made no sense

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server...

```
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @whereClause VARCHAR(max)

    SET @tableName = 'TableName' --you can change text to other table name
    SET @whereClause = ' WHERE -1 >= 0'

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT c.name
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) = @tableName

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
           SET @whereClause = @whereClause + ' OR '  + @name + ' >= 0'
           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName + @whereClause)
```